# How to define throughput profile for performance tests?

Tags: performance, gatling

[Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) defines a number of ways to define throughput profile for performance tests. Either through a number of arriving users:

```
setUp(
  scn.inject(
    nothingFor(4 seconds), // 1
    atOnceUsers(10), // 2
    rampUsers(10) over(5 seconds), // 3
    constantUsersPerSec(20) during(15 seconds), // 4
    constantUsersPerSec(20) during(15 seconds) randomized, // 5
    rampUsersPerSec(10) to(20) during(10 minutes), // 6
    rampUsersPerSec(10) to(20) during(10 minutes) randomized, // 7
    splitUsers(1000) into(rampUsers(10) over(10 seconds)) separatedBy(10 seconds), // 8
    splitUsers(1000) into(rampUsers(10) over(10 seconds)) separatedBy(atOnceUsers(30)), // 9
    heavisideUsers(1000) over(20 seconds) // 10
    ).protocols(httpConf)
  )
)
```

or by limiting a number of requests per second:

```
setUp(...).throttle(
  reachRps(100) in (10 seconds),
  holdFor(1 minute),
  jumpToRps(50),
  holdFor(2 hours)
)
```

Where can I learn how to define a proper throughput profile for my application? What cases should I focus on? I know it might be specific for my application but maybe there some generic introduction for defining throughput?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend sticking to "reality" approach if it is possible, so ideally it will be scenario 1. Also consider using appropriate [pause](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC5/general/scenario.html#pause)s to simulate real users think times as they don't hammer the application non-stop, they require some time before doing the next operation.

So I would rather go for "virtual users" as the approach and "throughput" as a metric, like "when X concurrent users use application it is able to serve Y requests per second", see [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) for more detailed explanation.

The "RPS" approach may be required if you're directly asked to measure it, like "according to SLA we need to serve X requests per second with response time not more than Y".